# UI Bootstrap dropdown for Angularjs shows multiple values repeatedly in Django

Tags: angularjs, django, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create a UI bootstrap dropdown in a Django project. 
This is my html code:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="mainController">
                <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
                    <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                        Discrete Distributions <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="simple-dropdown">
                        <li ng-repeat="discrete in discretes">
                            <a href>{% templatetag openvariable %} discrete {% templatetag closevariable %}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And this is my js code:

```
var stats = angular.module('stats', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap']);

stats.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log',
    function($scope, $log){
        $scope.discretes = ['Bernoulli', 'Binomial', 'Multinoulli', 'Multinomial', 'Geometric', 'Poisson']; 
}]);
```

Output looks like the below picture. I tried all dropdown codes in [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#). I am new at both Angularjs and Django but I think it is about Django. Unfortunately I couldn't find the reason. Please help me to find it.

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried displaying the raw value of 'discretes' onto the screen to see what it contains? This might help you to isolate the issue.

Comment: Interesting. Have you tried adding "track by $index" in your ng-repeat to see if it produces the correct values?